# CoreData crash: Database corrupted

Tags: ios, core-data, sqlite, nsmanagedobject

It seems like my SQLite database has got corrupted, I am not sure how.
I have a relationship in my model like `RemoteObject(remoteObject) <---> User(user)`

Now somehow, my persistentStore has reached a state where a `remoteObject` is pointing to an `author` that does not exist in the author table.

Basically, if I run the following query on the `ZREMOTEOBJECT` table, it returns **5** records-

`SELECT * FROM`ZREMOTEOBJECT`where ZAUTHOR >300`

However, if I run the following on `ZUSER` table, it returns **0** records-

`SELECT * FROM`ZUSER`where Z_PK >300`

So the problem here is that if I use `existingObjectWithID:` to get a `remoteObject`, the object is returned fine, but when I try to access `remoteObject.author`, it crashes with

`CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x180bc890 <x-coredata://64B7103E-5761-485B-8B4D-6B8174E786D0/User/p342>'`

Before the database had come to this state, the app had crashed. But I don't understand how the database could have been left in an inconsistent state. And now since this state is persisted, anytime I try to access the `author` of this `remoteObject`, it crashes and the app seems to be irrecoverable from this state, except by deleting the app and installing it again.

Please let me know if any other information will help in analyzing this problem.

**EDIT 1**

The relationship in more detail-

The relationship is defined both forward and backwards.

```
remoteObject.author --> User  (delete rule Cascade)
user.remoteObject --> RemoteObject (delete rule Nullify)
```

Comment: Have you defined a backward relationship for the `author` property? what is your deletion rule for this relationship?

Comment: @DanShelly : Edited the question to give more information about the relationships and delete rule